# Introduce implicit methods/fields into anonymous function

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm just getting started with `Scala` and I got stuck trying to create one particular object.

I have an object `IdentifierFactory` that I want to use to generate an `Identifier` instance. I have defined it like so:

```
object IdentifierFactory {
    def apply(f: => Any):Identifier = {
        f; validate

        Identifier(...)
    }

    def validate:Unit = ???
}
```

I want to be able to use it the following way:

```
IdentifierFactory {
    setName("name");
    addResource(resource);
}
```

How can I declare my `setName` and `addResource` (or alternatively `var`s that I can access) so that they are visible in the anonymous function only?

Comment: Not sure what that last sentence means. You want to access the results of `setName`, and `addResource`? If so, could you give an example of how'd you would use them, and how `validate` comes into play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a builder into your anonymous function:

```
IdentifierFactory { b =>
    b.setName("name")
    b.addResource(null)
}

object IdentifierFactory {
    trait Builder {
       def setName(name: String)
       def addResource(r: Any)
    }

    case class Identifier(name: String, rs: List[Any])

    def apply(f: Builder => Any):Identifier = {
        var nm = "default"
        var rs = List[Any]()
        f(new Builder {
           def setName(name: String) = nm = name 
           def addResource(r: Any) = rs ::= r
        })
        validate

        Identifier(nm, rs)
    }

    def validate: Unit = {}
}

scala> IdentifierFactory { b =>
 |         b.setName("name")
 |         b.addResource(null)
 |     }
res4: IdentifierFactory.Identifier = Identifier(name,List(null))
```

By the way, you can still do the same by just passing name and list of resources to the function with default values:

```
object IdentifierFactory {
    case class Identifier(name: String, rs: List[Any])

    def apply(nm: String = "default", rs: List[Any] = List[Any]()): Identifier = {          
        //validate it right here    
        Identifier(nm, rs)
    }

}

scala> IdentifierFactory()
res7: IdentifierFactory.Identifier = Identifier(default,List())

scala> IdentifierFactory(rs = List(null))
res8: IdentifierFactory.Identifier = Identifier(default,List(null))

scala> IdentifierFactory("nm", List(null))
res9: IdentifierFactory.Identifier = Identifier(nm,List(null))

scala> IdentifierFactory("nm")
res10: IdentifierFactory.Identifier = Identifier(nm,List())
```

I would also recommend returning an `Option` or `Either` instead of validation exception.

Comment: great, exactly what I needed :) Thanks for the tip re/ `Option`/`Either` too! :)